# Repositories (database gateway) in Clean Architecture

Tags: clean-architecture

I have been studying Robert Martin's Clean Architecture. I loved this book, but when I saw some tutorial and code that is supposed to be an example of clean architecture, I saw a repository interface declared in the Entities (enterprise business rules) layer, with methods referencing an Entities class (which means the repository implementation in the adapters layers depends directly on Entities layer, bypassing application layer). Although in this sample codes the dependency rule is followed, i have some question about it:

1. Wouldn't a repository interface fit better in application layer, since persistence is more an application rule then a core rule about the entities?
2. In his book, and also in [his blog article](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) (search for the "What data crosses the boundaries" subtitle), Uncle bob says that only simple data structures should be passed across the boundaries, never entities. So are this sample codes wrong?

Comment: When you are referring to "some tutorial and code " is that something in the book? If not: of course there are many bad code examples around, where either people interpreted the book wrong, or they just don't know how to do it, or they had to cut corners for some reason. In practical applications it's not achievable to have your code fully clean, often due to some constraints.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Wouldn't a repository interface fit better in application layer, since persistence is more an application rule then a core rule about the entities?

The repository interfaces are made to be used by interactors (aka. use cases). With the repository interface an interactor says what it wants but not how it is fulfilled. Thus they belong to the interactors and should therefore be placed in the use cases (application) layer.

I don't know the example you mentioned in your question, so I can't investigate it to see if there is some reason why the author put the repository interfaces in the entities layer and if it could have been solved in another way.

> 2. In his book, and also in his blog article (search for the "What data crosses the boundaries" subtitle), Uncle bob says that only simple data structures should be passed across the boundaries, never entities. So are this sample codes wrong?

Uncle Bob says

> **Typically** the data that crosses the boundaries is simple data structures.

and later

> For example, many database frameworks return a convenient data format in response to a query. We might call this a RowStructure. We don’t want to pass that row structure inwards across a boundary.
> Let me explain why I highlighted *typically*.

So what he doesn't want in his architecture is that classes, or any types, that are defined in the database layer appear in the entities or the interactors. Because this would be a dependency from higher level modules to details.

Sometimes there are use cases that some developers want to implement more relaxed, but it comes at a price.

E.g. when you have a *Show order details* and you have loaded the complete order entity in your interactor, you usually have to copy almost all data to the data structure that passed the boundary (the output port) in order to strictly follow the architecture.

You could also pass the entity to the output port, but this would violate the *strict* architecture rules. So if you want to follow the *strict* rules you must copy the data to a new data structure, if not you pass the entity to the output port.

But before you pass the entity directly to the output port, you should consider the pros and cons.

If you pass the entity to the output port, ou have a dependency from the interface adapters layer to the entity layer. The dependency rule that each dependency should point inwards is still applied, but the dependency skips one layer.

Such a relaxed architecture introduces the risk that e.g. controllers might invoke business methods on entities and that is what they shouldn't do. It's up to you to decide if you (and your colleagues) are diciplined enough to not invoke business methods from the controller or if you better protect yourself and others from doing it by introducing a new data structure and do the copy effort.

Answer (score 1):

From my point-of-view, which is a little more influenced by Domain-driven Design not only Clean Architecture, I see repositories as clear members of the domain layer (or business or core layer mostly referred to in clean architecture).

There are mainly two reasons for that:

**1. Repositories are domain services that contain logic that has a meaning to business people.**

Like finding an entity (aggregate) based on different criteria. For instance, a customer support employee, when on a support call, might have to search for an order either by the order number or if the customer does not have that they have to search by customer name and other criteria. The order repository would provide something like *findOrderByCustomerName()* which ***reflects the business language and needs***. So repositories can contain more than just methods to retrieve the entity and save the entity. In some cases they can also provide a primitive value. For instance, a repository for incident tickets could give you the number of unresolved tickets for a specific product. Again, it needs to fulfill some business logic related purpose.

**2. The domain (business) layer itself might need to consume a repository in order to perform some business logic.**

If business logic does not fit with one single entity it is often the case that some kind of [domain service](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-vs-application-services/) is needed that contains the required logic. And this ***service containing business logic could need access to a repository to fulfill its tasks***.

Let's say we have some company internal meeting room reservation application. If you want to make a new appointment there might be business logic that says that it must not be possible to schedule an appointment if there is already another appointment at the same time in the same meeting room. So the domain logic to ask if the requested meeting room is still free at that time might be part of the meeting room repository providing something like *IsRoomFreeAt(RoomId roomId, DateTime requestedMeetingTime)*. And there could be a service in the domain layer executing all the related business logic which needs this repository's functionality. Even if you don't want to apply that query pattern and rather just search for the respective meeting room and do check the free status of that room instead, it would be the same result.

If the one approach or the other would be more suited for the respective application use case is another question. The important part here is that the business logic to make sure no rooms are double booked requires some information from a repository, no matter how.

If the repository would be located in the *application layer* the ***dependencies would no longer be pointing inwards*** because now the domain (business) layer would have a dependency on the application layer and not just the other way around.

Comment: Well, the way i thought would be like: 1.Use case get some data, 2. then use case create entities, using that data or injecting the data passing simple structures to then, 3. then use case call some entitie method, 4. then use case can persist some result. But, you're  right, thinking about this example, it seems more simple to have a repository in the entities layer. But i guess we could have an repository or dao in infra layer returning simple dtos and also another repository in entity layer that uses that dao and converts dtos into entities. It would be good to decouple entities from ORMs.

Comment: I wasn't referring to using repositories in aggregates (which can make sense) but needing those in a domain service. I would also always favor prefetching data if possible. But sometimes it would not be feasible, for instance if there is logic that decides when to fetch what. And then you could end up with pre-fetching all the data from a repository, although the actual execution would just fetch a small portion based on the logical flow. And that can become very costly. But as always it depends and the use case. See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67261287/7730554